# Can I Advance an Unrezzed Ice in Netrunner?

Tags: android-netrunner

The rule book specifically prohibits advancing cards that cannot be advanced.

Ice generally cannot be advanced but there are a few exceptions.

Does the exception apply when it's face down?

**What I'm asking is: Can you advance an advancable ice that is unrezzed?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, unless otherwise noted on the card text.
I couldn't find this specifically addressed in the [FAQ](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/android-netrunner/support/FAQ/Android-Netrunner%20FAQ.pdf), but it's pretty easy to reason out the answer if you look at [all the Ice that can be advanced](http://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=t%3AICE%20x%3A%22can%20be%20advanced%22&sort=name&view=spoiler&_locale=en). For example, [several cards](http://netrunnerdb.com/find/?q=t%3AICE%20x%3A%22can%20be%20advanced%20only%20while%20rezzed%22&sort=name&view=spoiler&_locale=en) have something like this:

> Tyrant can be advanced only while rezzed

This implies that the others can be advanced while unrezzed. To really drive the point home, [Wormhole](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/07013) says:

> Wormhole can be advanced and its rez cost is lowered by 3 for each
>   advancement token on it.

[image: Image of Tyrant card]

Comment: Those are good examples, but all you needed was this: *Note: If a card’s text box says that the card can be advanced, the
card can be advanced even when the card is unrezzed.* Rulebook, page 14

Comment: Good point! My only defense is that perhaps the rules pdf has been updated in the last 2 years, but it's at least equally likely that I just didn't search hard enough. :)